# Service Fabric: Addressing stateless services externally using the fabric:/ address scheme.

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-gateway

My company would like the ability to deploy many public facing stateless service instances to our nodes without having to specify a port number for the service.

It seems that Service Fabric already supports the ability to route traffic using the Naming Service by the known fabric address. It also supports mapping to DNS names through the DNS Service. Either of these options seem pretty well suited to our requirement.

I've had a pretty thorough search on the internet trying to find a way to address these services externally using some form of Layer 7 stack (ideally using Application Gateway) but I'm drawing a blank.

I have found the [following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-api-management-quick-start) showing how the API Management product has integrated with Service Fabric. It seems the Azure team have a perfect working implementation here but no documentation on how to achieve this setup using an alternative gateway.

Is there any reference material for how we can configure a product such as Application Gateway to suit our needs?

Many thanks

---

Duplicate ticket raised with [service-fabric-issues tracker](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/416).

Comment: Did you see they mention a github repo that has a sample deployment template? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-api-management

Answer (score 0):

Service Fabric v5+ ships with a reverse proxy which would be a good fit in this case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy